# read and calculate a value from json url file

Tags: jquery, json

I want to show how many euros my 0.128 litecoin make.
How to calculate the euro price multiplied with 0.128 ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> </head>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
    $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2/?convert=EUR', function(data) {

        var text = `0.128 * parseFloat(${data.data.quotes.EUR.price})`


        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>
     </body> </html>
```

Comment: `var text = 0.128 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;` ?

Comment: why using template literals...backtick ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to parse your result : the result is already a float type.

You can round it if you want.

Here is a working code :

JavaScript - read JSON from URL

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2/?convert=EUR', function(data) {

    var text = 0.128 *  data.data.quotes.EUR.price

    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});

</script>
 </body> </html>
```

And a JSFiddle to play with :

http://jsfiddle.net/6rzk2n54/1/

Answer (score 0):

In the function you do should not use `data` in a JQuery-ish manner. It is pure JavaScript inside, like:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
      var res = 0.128 * parseFloat(data.data.quotes.EUR.price)
        


        $(".mypanel").html(res);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
  <title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```